# CSS - highlight a selected tab

Tags: asp.net, css, navigation

I have the following tabbed navigation setup in my master page.

```
        <nav class="grid_12">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="selected">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

When I click on the Portfolio tab, for example, I'd like the Portfolio tab to remain highlighted when I land on the portfolio page.
What is the recommended way to accomplish this?

I have checked some other posts, but [the most relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385035/jquery-selected-tab-problem) of those uses divs in the example as opposed to separate pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the "selected" class name you have has the styling for the highlight you're talking about. After the user clicks on one of those links, with jquery you can add "selected" class to the clicked anchor tag. put this at the bottom of your page right before the closing body tag or in your main JavaScript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".grid_12 ul li a").click(function() {
            $(".grid_12 ul li a ").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected")
        })
    })
</script>
```

The code above will only work if there is no page refresh and only content refresh, however if your page will refresh and go to a new page I would do something like this:

```
<nav class="grid_12">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav_home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav_portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav_blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav_contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

and add the styling for specific pages. For example when you're on www.mySite.com/portfolio in the css for portfolio ONLY add:

```
a.nav_portfolio{
    background-color:orage;
    ...
}
```

This way you don't even have to do any javascript.

Comment: I just tried this, but no such luck. I placed your code inside the head tag.
Does this have to be implemented in all ASPX pages that I will be using, or would implementing it in the Master page be enough?

Comment: Put it at the bottom of the page right before the closing </body> tag. Here's the entire code:

Comment: Except for one small problem: When I click on the Portfolio tab, it goes to the portfolio page, sets the "selected" class then removes it. I have tried adding "return false" after $(this).addClass("selected"), but this causes the link to not work.

Comment: that makes sense.. since the page refreshes. What does your URL Structure look like for the different pages?

Comment: The navigation currently looks like this:
        <nav class="grid_12">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
All of the pages are on the same level.